# Any issues mounting nikkor 600mm f5.6 ais on a canon dslr

Tags: canon, nikon, lens-adapter

When looking at long prime lenses I failed to find a reasonably prised canon ef mount 600mm lens. I did however find the nikkor 600mm f5.6 for less than 700$ on ebay (as well as some old mediumformat lenses). Given that this is a manual focus lens will there be any issues using it on a full frame canon dslr with an adapter?

An ideal answer would be someone who has tested the combination. I will accept good answers withou that if none are forthcomming.

Comment: Related question: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000)

Comment: @scottbb I have read that, this question was more intended to flush out issues specific to this combination rather than a general does F mount lenses adapt to EOS at all. Thanks nevertheless

Comment: Understood. That's why I linked it as related, rather than voted as a duplicate. In addition, for future readers coming across your question, some of the related issues brought in the linked question may be relevant to them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Nikon lenses on Canon EOS cameras with a simple glass-less adapter.

[Nikon to Canon adapters at B&H Photo](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?ci=3420&N=4077634486%204289371108%204289371044&origSearch=Nikon%20to%20Canon%20adapter)

I have not used the Nikon 600mm f/5.6 but I have used other Nikon lenses. I assume you know that focus and aperture will have to be set manually on the lens. I see no reason why the 600mm lens would not be just as usable as any other Nikon lens.

If you use Aperture priority auto exposure, the camera will try to set the shutter speed to get a correct exposure. The camera assumes metering based on a wide open aperture so if you stop down the lens you might get exposure errors. I always shot manual mode and then corrected the exposure using the image review on the rear LCD.